# FFMPEG Crear un Video a partir de imagenes con pista de audio en blanco

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Quiero crear un video a partir de unas imagenes para usar en el programa DashWare.
Uno de los requisitos es que el video ha de tener una pista de audio.

Si creo una secuencia de JPG y los uno con un audio, el resultado es el deseado.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 29.97 -i Pictures_%5d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -vf scale="2560:1440" output.mp4
```

Me gustaria hacerlo mejor y me gustaria que al crearse el video directamente se crease una pista de audio en blanco.
He conseguido hacerlo con esta secuencia pero tengo el problema que se genera un video sin fin. Si pones una clausula -t entonces el video dura lo que indicas, pero yo no quiero hacero así ya que es para hacer diferentes video y tendrán una duración diferente.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -framerate 29.97 -i Pictures_%5d.jpg  -vf scale="2560:1440" Output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es añadir la cláusula -shortest

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -framerate ntsc -i Pictures_% 5d.jpg -vf "scale=2560:1440" -shortest Output.mp4
```